# How to configure a newsletter subscription with Sitecore 8.1, WFFM and EXM

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-ecm, sitecore-exm

I am new to sitecore developement and have one task to acheive using EXM and WFFM.
I have one newsletter subscription form which contains

1. Name
2. Email Address
3. Option to subscribe for News Letter or Current Vacancies
4. Captcha

Clicking on Submit, should send Email to the user with link to verify his email address. After clicking on link user will be added in email subscription list to receive newsletter and/or current openings.

I am not sure from where to start to implement this functionality. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Mohit, this sounds like a small standalone project and it's hard to detail every single step in here, but I will at least point you on how to get started.

First of all, let me briefly explain the two Sitecore modules and how you can make them work togheter:

- **WFFM:** Lets you create simple web forms that record and report information provided by visitors to your website
- **EXM**: Lets you  create and manage email messages, and manage subscription lists

In order to achive your project, you need to:

1. Create two subscription lists: ***Newsletter Subscription List*** and ***Current Vacancies Subscription List***. [Here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/the_list_manager/creating_lists/create_a_contact_list_or_a_segmented_list) are some instructions
2. Create the subscription form, containing the two subscription options. You can follow this detailed article from Sitecore, which explains [how to create a form](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/using_web_forms/creating_web_forms/create_and_insert_a_web_form).
3. Trigger **Confirmation email** on WFFM submit and subscribe users to your lists: if you follow [this article](https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.be/2015/09/wffm-subscription-messages-to-contact.html), you will understand how to add the "Subscribe to Recipient List" save action and to trigger a Subscription confirmation email
4. **Configure EXM:**  [Create a new message in EXM](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/getting_started_with_exm/messages/create_a_message), which [includes your subscription lists](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/getting_started_with_exm/messages/include_or_exclude_recipients_of_a_message) as recipients list

I hope this helps you get started.

Comment: Thanks! Adrian. I will go through the steps you mentioned.

Comment: The included Subscription Form control does all of this, reference that as well while following these steps.